# looping through two lists while updating one of the lists

Tags: lisp, iteration, common-lisp

I have two lists as follows:

```
(x y z) & (2 1)
```

and I want to have a result like:

```
((x y) (z))
```

The relation of the lists is quite clear. So basically I want to rearrange the members of the first list into a list of lists with two (length of second list) lists.
I have tried running two dotimes iterations to do this:

```
(let ((result) (list1* list1))
   (dotimes (n (length list2) result)
     (progn (setq result
                  (append result
                          (list (let ((result2))
                                  (dotimes (m (nth n list2) result2)
                                    (setq result2
                                         (append result2
                                                 (list (nth m list1*)))))))))
            (setq list1*
                 (subseq list1* 0 (nth n list2))))))
```

The idea is that I make the first list of the expected result (x y), and then I want to update the (x y z) list so that the x any y are removed and I only have (z). Then the loop runs again to get the (z) list in the expected result. This does not work correctly and results in:

```
 ((x y) (x))
```

which means apparently the second command for progn which is basically updating the list1* is not working. Clearly there must be a correct and better way of doing this and I was wondering whether anyone can help with this. Also explain why it is not possible to have the solution explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I see that right, your problem is in `(subseq list1* 0 (nth n list2))`, which returns the part of the list that you do *not* want.

I have the following to offer:

```
(defun partition-list (list lengths)
  (mapcar (lambda (length)
            (loop :repeat length
                  :collect (pop list)))
          lengths))
```

This is a bit simplistic, of course, as it does not handle unexpected input, such as `(length list)` being smaller than `(reduce #'+ lengths)`, but it can be expanded upon.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of example, an alternative using `iterate`:

```
(defun partition-list (list by)
  (iter:iter
    (iter:for element in list)
    (iter:for i from 1)
    (iter:generating measure in by)
    (iter:collect element into sublist)
    (when (= (or measure (iter:next measure)) i)
      (iter:collect sublist)
      (iter:next measure)
      (setf i 0 sublist nil))))
```

Comment: I think that `iterate` is a library that to `use-package` really pays off in legibility.

Comment: @Svante yes. The reason I did it when posting is so not to get the reader confused about where it comes from. For those using SLIME it may take a while to figure out the steps they need to do to get the example running (if you don't `use-package` and try to eval the code that assumes that you do, then you'll get generic errors, which will not help you much in understanding of what you had to do).